# generating API and laravel passport

Tags: laravel, api, filter, resources, laravel-passport

I'm new to Laravel and kindly answer my question, please.

I'm developing a system with Laravel 5.8 in which two user levels are included.

1. user
2. admin

Authenticated users can view and store the posts into database. (action: `index`, `show` and `store`)

And authenticated admins can view the posts that the users have posted and approve to publish. (action: `index`, `show`, `store` and `destroy`)

My database table:books is like below:

id

name

numbers_of_pages

type

author

and users table:

id

name

email

password

and admins table:

id

name

email

password

**First Question:**

In my `api.php`

```
Route::apiResource('books', 'BookController');
```

Follow is my desired routes structrues.

```
# index()
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/drama -> get all books where type is drama
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/novel -> get all books where type is novel
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/magazine -> get all books where type is magazine
```

How can I achieve that with my BookController created by the command:

```
php artisan make:controller BookController --api
```

and how to prefix *v1* in the route? I don't want to prefix that version number in RouteServiceProvider.php.

**Another Question:**
How to oauth that multiple users? Both admins and users are consumers of the api.

Comment: why do you not want the `v1` prefix set in the RouteServiceProvider ... and the `auth` middleware can take parameters for different guards you want to check

Comment: thanks. How can I get that ```novel```, ```drama```, or ```magazine``` in the BookController from route?

Comment: it will be passed as an argument to your `show` method ... for those URLs you are showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For i am developing an api myself at this moment, i know some of your problems and have already succeded to complete this task, so i try to answer your questions.

To the 'v1' prefix in URL: I have done this in my `routes/api.php` file with

```
Route::prefix('/v1')->group(function () { 
// my routes for version 1
}
```

One word for your user/admin stuff: I did not put this into 2 seperate tables. The idea is, that you have a bunch of users and only some of them are admins. So why don't flag them with an `admin` flag and give the users model (in your `User.php`) a method with `is_admin` to just return, if this flag is set to `true` or `false`. So you can see, is a logged in user an admin or not.

With this, you can check this at any time in your app with `auth()->user()->is_admin` to see, if this is an admin or not.

Hope, i could help you a little bit

Now, to your `Books` problem.
I would simply put in another route into my `routes/api.php` like

```
Route::get('books/{category}', 'BookController@category')->name('books.category');
```

and create a new function called `public function category(String $category)` into my `BookController`. Within this, you can check if `$category` is a valid Category Name and handle the return.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindly answer. The ```prefix``` works. For the user/admin case, if I need to use two tables for some reasons: users and admins, is it possible to use ```laravel passport``` to authenticate both user type? I think ```passport``` have configuration only for **users** table. If it is not possible, and I need to use two tables and I want to achieve that authentication feature, what is the option for me?

Comment: sry, never had this requirement in 20 yrs now, but take a look at the passport configuration, maybe you can find informations there. But i really think, there is no use for two tables 

Comment: Thank you so much.